# Swift 1.2 Results to '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Updating to Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3 caused the following errors:

[image]

Could someone with understanding of changes that took place between 1.1 and 1.2 help out what's going on here? All help appreciated! Thanks for reading this far!

Comment: It's because optional issue.. Can you show me your full source code?

Comment: I can but as far as I can tell there's no relevancy anywhere else. I'm iterating over the spritekit node tree and if the node has name and it's "paintedArea" I want to do stuff. However this error keeps popping up. If I remove the "?" the code complies ok but what happens when a node doesn't have a name?

Comment: Martin: this question is NOT duplicate of what you're suggesting

Comment: Actually it _is_ a duplicate of what @MartinR suggested. And the answer I give there is the answer. Delete the `?`. It serves no purpose, and in Swift 1.2 that fact is called out clearly by the compiler.

Comment: The reasoning behind removing the "?" wasn't clear in this context. Thanks to Vacawama for spelling it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 1.2, it is illegal to follow a variable with `?` to unwrap it.  The `?` is used in an *optional chain* and must then be followed by a method call, a member lookup (i.e. a property), or a subscript as the error message said.

In the comments you added:

> If I remove the "?" the code complies ok but what happens when a node
>   doesn't have a name?

It is perfectly valid to compare a `String?` to a literal `String` value without unwrapping the variable first.  If the optional is `nil`, then `nil` is not equal to any literal `String` so the `if` will simply fail.

Try the following in a Swift Playground:

```
var str: String? = nil

if str == "hello" {
    println("it is hello")
} else {
    println("not hello")  // prints "not hello"
}

// Here we reassign str, but it is still a String?    
str = "hello"

if str == "hello" {
    println("it is hello")  // prints "it is hello"
} else {
    println("not hello")
}
```

So it is completely safe just just compare `paintedNode.name` to `"paintedArea"` and if the node doesn't have a name then `paintedNode.name` will be `nil` and the `if` will fail just as if it had a different name.